# Returning a list of projection from a custom JpaRepository method with Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a simple Spring Boot application that has Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Rest modules.

Spring Data Rest automatically exposes JPA Repositories but when I send an HTTP GET request to a custom search method in the repository which returns a List of projection  I get `Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117!`. When I change the return type of the method from list of projections to just a projection it just works fine.

Person Entity class

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;
}
```

Person Repository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<NameProjection> findByNameContains(@Param(value = "name") String name);
}
```

Projection

```
@Projection(name = "nameProjection", types = {Person.class})
public interface NameProjection {
    String getName();
}
```

URL: http://localhost:8080/persons/search/findByNameContains?name=a

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.lambda$getRequiredPersistentEntity$2(PersistentEntities.java:78) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:72) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:55) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:110) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.toResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:80) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.lambda$toResource$1(RepositorySearchController.java:209) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.toResource(RepositorySearchController.java:206) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(RepositorySearchController.java:190) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

There is an example project at https://github.com/mahsumdemir/projection-demo to show the error. After starting project go to http://localhost:8080/persons/search/findByNameContains?name=i url and you will see the error.

**UPDATE**

I want to return `List<NameProjection>` because Spring Data JPA uses the return type of repository method to determine the SQL that will be executed on the database. Calling a method with return type of `List<Person>` executes `select * from person;` on database. But calling a method with return type of `List<NameProjection>` executes `select name from person;` on the database. The extra data gathered from the database is not a problem in case of Person entity. But it is a big problem while operating on an entity which has multimedia columns.

**UPDATE 2**

Related jira issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1237

Answer (score 5):

***Spring Data REST*** allows **multiple** projections. And you can pass the desired projection via an url-parameter

example:  */persons/search/nickname?name=r&**projection=surname***

so in your Repository you don't need to retrun **NameProjection**, just return **Person**

```
 public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
  List<Person> findByNameContains(@Param(value = "name") String name);
 }
```

and call */persons/search/findByNameContains?name=a&**projection=nameProjection*** and you should be fine.

have a look at this [demo](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/projection-demo)

Comment: Without Param annotation I get  "Unable to detect parameter names. Use Param or compile with -parameters on JDK 8 ". I removed Projection annotation and tried again but nothing has changed.

Comment: The project you have provided does not use spring-boot-starter-data-rest project. With this project, repository methods get exposed by default so we don't need a sperate RestController class. I have provided a project at https://github.com/mahsumdemir/projection-demo . After starting project go to the http://localhost:8080/persons/search/findByNameContains?name=i url and you will see the error I'm talking about.

Comment: my bad, assumed you meant accessing data via a rest-controller, **corrected my answer**, hope it helps

Comment: I want to return `List<NameProjection>` because Spring Data JPA uses the return type of repository method to determine the SQL that will be executed on the database. Calling a method with return type of `List<Person>` executes `select * from person;` on database. But calling a method with return type of `List<NameProjection>` executes `select name from person;` on the database. The extra data gathered from the database is not a problem in case of Person entity. But it is a big problem while operating on an entity which has multimedia columns.

Comment: `List<NameProjection>` executes `select name from person;` I don't think so, have a try with a @Restcontroler and set property `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

Comment: Yes, like you told, spring does not optimize query executed on the database in the project I provided. I looked at spring documentation and it says: "If a closed projection is used, Spring Data modules can even optimize the query execution as we exactly know about all attributes that are needed to back the projection proxy." I updated the project. Now, it shows the case that I mentioned. Documentation can be found @ https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.closed

Answer (score 1):

I found a a workaround, quite ugly but works. I created the projection as an Entity instead of interface (statistic of my event)

Then I created a legit repo for this new class, but never uses it as a repo (just autogenerates table but nothing in it)

I was doing a group by to get statistics for one item, like this I can get the result as I wanted it

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface IStatisticRepository extends CrudRepository<Statistic, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select rownum() as id, category as category, categorySum as category_sum " +
            "from (select i.category as category, sum(pi.qty) as categorySum " +
            "from item i " +
            "left join participation_item pi on i.id = pi.item_id " +
            "left join participation p on p.id = pi.participation_id " +
            "left join event e on p.event_id = e.id " +
            "where e.id=:eventId " +
            "group by i.category )")
    List<Statistic> getByIdToStatistic(Long eventId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As workaround You can call repo method through a helper controller like below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PersonsController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repo;

    @GetMapping("/persons")
    public List<NameProjection> findByNameContains(@RequestParam(name="name") String name) {
        return repo.findByNameContains(name);
    }

}
```

Calling `http://localhost:8080/api/persons?name=a` You will get response without HATEOAS stuff however (what may be sometimes useful)

```
[
  {
    "name": "Adam"
  },
  {
    "name": "Anna"
  }
]
```

You can mark repository method with `@RestResource(exported = false)` to not export this method by Spring Data Repository interface directly (`/persons/search/...` call).